# Creating a Clickable Box

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a 30x30 pixel box. I don't care if it uses a button, a, span, whatever.

I can't get anything to show up uniformly across all browsers.

Here are the requirements:

1. Must append to the end of an
   existing line (no line breaks)
2. Must be able to assign click events in jQuery
3. Must be a square
4. Appears flat with no sort of bevel

Comment: Would you like else with that? Fries or a coke? Place your order at the next counter please =P

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have your HTML and CSS that have not worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want simply by styling an 'A' tag in your css.

**CSS:**

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href=""></a>
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fQP6J/1/

Comment: this breaks rule 1 `Must append to the end of an existing line (no line breaks)`

Comment: I had exactly what you had minus the `display:inline-block;` part. thanx!

Comment: Too easy @Dex. I also sometimes forget that sneaky little bugger =P

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<style>

.btn {

BORDER: 1px solid;  COLOR: black; height: 30px; width: 30px;

}

</style>

<button class=btn >btn</button>

</html>
```